# how to map domain name to dynamic ip address

Tags: linux, ip-address, dynamic

I have registered a domain www.blah.com and I would like to point this domain to my home computer which it is using adsl with dynamic ip address.

More info: My router has dyndns client and my computer uses linux.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this home use question more suited to serverfault.com than webmasters?

Comment: Not sure why the OP got a negative vote.  If it came from SF, it's not the OPs fault it got migrated to the wrong place.  It appears he actually asked it in the correct location.

Answer (score 3):

I did this by setting up www.blah.com as a CNAME pointing to blah.dyndns.org . My router keeps the dyndns information current. Make sure you keep the ttl field low in your zone file, so any changes get picked up quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your router to update a dyndns domain and then cname your blah.com domain to it.